# If I am developing a hosted payments page, what should the infrastructure look like?

Tags: architecture

If I am not storing credit card info, do I have to be concerned with [PCI-compliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Compliance)?

I will be using a payment processor with a bank in my country. Literally just taking the credit card info and passing it to the gateway and processor. I would love to get an idea of the various technologies I might need to consider from an software architectural point of view.

What are the best practices in terms of accepting credit cards and reducing fraud risk on my end?

I will be creating the app in Rails.

Comment: Part of PCI compliance deals with _transport_ as well, which it sounds like what you're doing; that is, the customer gives you the credit card number, and it's present in application memory, but never persisted to a database (although this is not as straightforward or robust as may be imagined).  If you want to avoid those headaches, I'd recommend attempting to use processor that provides an API that absolves you of the need to even collect the card information (ie PayPal).

Answer (score 1):

PCI regulations are not US laws, they are rules put forth by the various credit card companies, being outside of the US doesn't exempt you from complying with them.

First thing to determine is what payment processor you are going to use, that will pretty much set the direction for everything else.

Comment: You are right. I am reading up about PCI-compliance.

I will be using a payment processor with a bank in my country. I don't plan on storing any CC numbers, will I still need to be PCI-compliant? Literally just taking the credit card info and passing it to the gateway and processor.

I would love to get an idea of the various technologies I might need to consider from an software architectural point of view.

Comment: @marcamillion: you will need to talk to your payment processor about that.  You will have to comply with whatever regs they have.